# Camel REST DSL set Example Value for Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, rest, apache-camel, swagger

Is it possible and if yes, how to set the Example Value for Swagger UI using Camel REST DSL in Java?

I'm running Swagger UI from org.webjars dependency in Spring Boot.

```
rest("/test").description("Some description").consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .post("/trigger").id("trigger")
                .description("Another description")
                .type(Map.class).param().name("body").type(body).description("More description"))
                .required(true).example(readJson.getJson("json_example.txt")).endParam()
                .route().bean(new Service(), "Trigger");
```

This `readJson` get JSON as String.
It looks like `.example()` is ignored and nothing appears in Swagger UI.

It always shows the "string" value inside Example Value like on the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, I've created Java POJO class with next code:

```
public class User{
    public String user_id;
    public String user_name;
}
```

Then I linked that class to the Camel REST DSL inside SpringBootRouter class:

```
...
rest("/test").description("Some description").consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
                .post("/trigger").id("trigger")
                .description("Another description")
                .type(User.class).param().name("body").type(body).description("More description"))
                .required(true).endParam()
                .route().bean(new Service(), "Trigger");
...
```

And this is the result:

[image]

If there is a better solution, please tell.

UPDATE:

To replace default value `"string"` for String or `0` for int or `true` for Boolean, I've used `ApiModelProperty` like this:

```
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
    
public class User{
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "1165")
    public String user_id;
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "Bob")
    public String user_name;
}
```

And this is the final result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In swagger v3 you use

```
@Model(description = "The user name", example = "Bob")
public String user_name;
```